# Gunicorn will only work as root user, else throws "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

Im working on a production server deployed on an AWS EC2 instance.

The project is made with django, and its running on nginx + gunicorn

After a few trials, I got everything working, however, when I added the `--user nginx` flag, the app stopped working.
When run as a service, the service initialices properly, but then on any request it will throw an error 500. When run directly from command line, it does not even start.

The command, which is the same on the gunicorn.service file as the one I run from cli is:

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --preload --user nginx --chdir /home/ec2-user/api/ project.wsgi:application  --bind 0:8000 --workers=3 --timeout=120 --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error.log --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log --reload
```

On either case, the stack traces as follows:

```
[2023-04-14 20:35:19 +0000] [5429] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5429)
[2023-04-14 20:35:19 +0000] [5430] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5430
[2023-04-14 20:35:19 +0000] [5430] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
[2023-04-14 20:35:19 +0000] [5430] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5430)
[2023-04-14 20:35:19 +0000] [5427] [WARNING] Worker with pid 5430 was terminated due to signal 15
[2023-04-14 20:35:19 +0000] [5427] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2023-04-14 20:35:19 +0000] [5427] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

The module project does exist, and as I mentioned earlier, if I remove the --user nginx flag, the server runs perfectly, altough, you can imagine why I dont want to run my application as root.

I've already changed ownership of the project, and still nothing changed.

removing the user flag from the command works, but is not the desired solution.

On the service file, the user variable was leading to issues, so I removed it fisrt, which got the app running, but then when I added the flag to the command the errors started appearing.

The gunicorn.service file looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --preload --user nginx --chdir /home/ec2-user/api/ project.wsgi:application  --bind 0:8000 --workers=3 --timeout=120 --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error.log --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log --reload
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

as a service, gunicorn starts but fails on any request. When run directly as a command, gunicorn doesnt start, throwing a ModuleNotFoundError on the wsgi file, doenst matter the path to the file I use (project/wsgi:application, project.wsgi:application, /home/ec2-user/api/project.wsgi:application, etc)

On either case, the problem seems to be the related to the access the process has to the project files